# Scrapy: Following links of Json Objects returned by Rest API

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, scrapy

I am implementing a spider which is supposed to get all url links from
this page (and all other by pagination): https://www.ibm.com/search?lang=de&cc=de&q=iot. I am able to do that by using the api.

Here is my problem:
I don't know how I can follow the links that I extracted since the Link Extractor from Scrapy only works with Selectors not Json Objects.

When trying to scrape the url with a second request like this:

```
url = result.get('url')
content = scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_content)
```

I only get something like this for the content variable: `Request GET http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10884852`

Please help.
Here is my full code:

```
import scrapy
import json


class IbmSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ibm_spider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.ibm.com/search?lang=de/']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls_=[]            
        for i in range(0,10):
                urls_.append('https://www-api.ibm.com/api/v1/search/aggr/rest/appid/mh?bookmark=eyJzZXJ2aWNlTmFtZSI6Imtub3dsZWRnZUNlbnRlciIsInRvdGFsIjoyOTMzNSwiY291bnQiOjMsInNtQ291bnQiOjAsIm9mZnNldCI6NiwiZmFpbGVkUGFnZXMiOltdfS17InNlcnZpY2VOYW1lIjoiZXNxcyIsInRvdGFsIjo0MDE3MywiY291bnQiOjE3LCJzbUNvdW50IjoyLCJvZmZzZXQiOjMyLCJmYWlsZWRQYWdlcyI6W119LXsicGFnZSI6MywicXVlcnkiOiJpb3QifQ&cachebust=1559896290619&dict=spelling&fr=60&nr=20&page={0}&query=iot&rc=de&refinement=ibmcom&rmdt=entitled&sm=true&smnr=20MzNSwiY291bnQiOjMsInNtQ291bnQiOjAsIm9mZnNldCI6NiwiZmFpbGVkUGFnZXMiOltdfS17InNlcnZpY2VOYW1lIjoiZXNxcyIsInRvdGFsIjo0MDE3MywiY291bnQiOjE3LCJzbUNvdW50IjoyLCJvZmZzZXQiOjMyLCJmYWlsZWRQYWdlcyI6W119LXsicGFnZSI6MywicXVlcnkiOiJpb3QifQ'.format(i))
        for url in urls_:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        results = data.get('resultset').get('searchresults').get('searchresultlist')
        for result in results:
            url = result.get('url')
            content = scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_content)
            yield {
                'title':  result.get('title'),
                'url':  url,
                # added to extract Links content
                'content': content
            }

    def parse_content(self,response):
        return response.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `parse` function you should yield not dict, but content request. Check this example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    results = data.get('resultset').get('searchresults').get('searchresultlist')
    for result in results:
        url = result.get('url')
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_content, meta={'title': result.get('title')})
```

So, in `parse_content` you can get title, url and content of request:

```
def parse_content(self, response):
    # and your logics here
    print response.meta['title']
    print response.url
    print response.text
```